# How to create a list with bigger font in markdown

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using markdown in jupyter, so I create bullet lists the usual way :

> - Item1
>
> - Item2

which appears as :

- Item1
- Item2

Now say I want the font of the list to be bigger, e.g. like the one provided by heading 2 (`##`), is there a way to do it? What I tried

> # - Item1
>
> # - Item2

fails and appears simply as header text and not as a bigger list :

## - Item1

## - Item2

Comment: @skar that just makes `item 1` a header :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the hashtags come after the hyphen, like so   - ## item1

- ### item1